# Laravel - high CPU usage after deployment

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

I have a serious problem with deployment of Laravel app. It's a news website, nothing complicated. Whole homepage is cached in Redis as a plain HTML, also queries results are stored in Redis so MySQL usage is really small. App is fully functional so we decided to test it in production environment during the night. After deployment we noticed that CPU usage jumped to 90-100% on all 12 cores so the app was working very slow or not working at all. There were about 400 users, 17-20 requests per second.

We tried to change server settings (PHP-FPM ex.) but with no success. We made some tests using Apache Benchmark and it showed that with 10 concurrent users CPU usage is about 80-100%. Next we repeat tests with clean Laravel (without our app) and results were similar.

What we use:

- Laravel 9.0
- server: 12 cores, 128 GB RAM
- Plesk Obsidian 18.0.48, CentOS 7.9.2009
- Apache + Nginx as a reverse proxy

We noticed that Nginx caching can reduce CPU usage in applications like Wordpress or Drupal. But I suppose that Laravel doesn't use it. Does Laravel need to be configured to work with Nginx reverse proxy and caching in some special way?

I really don't know what to do. Had anyone a similar problem?

Comment: Nginx caching works across everything. when you had those CPU spikes, did you check which process was killing the server?  (i bet it was DB).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Php-fpm pool processes were kilking the server. High CPU usage was constanty high. DB is not a reason because it is running on separate server and there CPU usage is about 2-3%.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel runs pretty well on Nginx. I run my App in a container on Google Cloud with Nginx, without any performance trouble.

If you want to use a reserver proxy, this one did the job for me:

```
server {

listen 80;

your_news_app.com;

location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

}

Comment: Well, our nginx config is similar to yours. It looks like framework loading on each request consume so much CPU. When I use PHP without Laravel CPU works normally :(